# How to perform multiple agg operations on same column of a spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, aggregation

Helllo friends ,

I have the following function signature

```
def groupAndAggregate(inputDS: Dataset[Row], aggregateFunMap: Map[String, String], aggregateColumns: List[String]):Dataset[Row]={
// statements
  }
```

Where aggregateFunMap is a Map contains columns as key and corresponding aggregate operation to be performed

Eg :- `val aggregateFunMap=Map("amount"->"avg","amount"->"sum")`

And , `aggregateColumns` is a List which contains columns that is used to group by operation

Eg:- `val aggregateColumns=List("amount")`

I have the following code to find the final result after performing the group by operation and the aggregation .

```
{
   val grouped = inputDS.groupBy(aggregateColumns.head, aggregateColumns.tail: _*)
   grouped.agg(aggregateFunMap)
}
```

But when i passed Map with multiple aggregation operations on the same column it returns an incorrect result ie ; the final dataframe contains only one aggregation operation .

If some one can help me , it will be great help for me .